# What is the correct punctuation in the sentence "Shall I open the window or you will do it"

Tags: punctuation, questions, question-mark, indirect-question

I have a sentence:

> Shall I open the window or you will do it.

I wonder whether the second half of the sentence is **grammatically correct** (is it an indirect question?) and whether or not we need a **question mark** at the end of the sentence to convey the meaning of a *question*.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why would you not put a question mark at the end of a question?

Comment: So does it need a question mark?

Comment: I thought there might be some special rules about indirect questions like that. Is the grammar here correct?

Comment: Yes. It's a question do it needs a question mark (?).

Comment: In the source where I found it there is no question mark, just a period.

Comment: That's why I wonder.

Comment: I don't see any way to make that sound correct without swapping `you` and `will` around (and also adding a question mark).

Comment: Yes, it should be "...or will you do it?"